# Pass an enum to a function taking a reference to int

Tags: c++, casting, enums

dereferencing type-punned

I have an enum

```
enum AgentStatus { kSTOPPED = 0, kRUNNING, kIDLE, kNAGENTSTATUS };
```

I need to pass it to a function of an external library with many overloaded variants. I want to pass it to the second argument:

```
DimService::DimService(const char*, int&);
DimService::DimService(const char*, char*);
...
```

If I do a cast to (int&) of my enum variable, I get the infamous warning :

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

If I do a cast to (int) I get this

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char*’
error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘DimService::DimService(const char*, char*)’
```

What is the correct way ?

Comment: To use an int variable, and not casting.

Comment: it a reference, do not meed to cast

Comment: `enum AgentStatus : int { ...` ? Add `as_lvalue`?

Comment: Notice that you are defining a constructor with a return type: that is illegal

Comment: @AndyProwl I assumed DimService was a namespace, which matches the sentence "I need to pass it to a function of an external library with many overloaded variants" quite well.

Comment: @Agentlien: Right, makes sense

Comment: @AndyProwl Though that begs the question whether a function with the same name as the namespace in which it lies is really a good design.

Comment: @Agentlien: True again, perhaps this is why I failed to consider this possible scenario

Comment: @AndyProwl Indeed, it was a bad copy paste, I have edited the post. It is a constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer from Bill is the correct answer technically.

1) Another approach

Another way to do this if you need to get rid of the enum-ness of the type is to make the type an int itself.

```
typedef int MyEnum;
enum
{
    CONST1 = 0,
    etc...
};
```

And then just use it like normal. The compiler will not catch bad assignments of values, but since you can tag all the declarations as MyEnum type it should be simple enough to follow what is happening, and you can just pass the variables anywhere that it says int.

2) Dangerous approach

NEVER DO THIS!

```
EnumType v = EnumValue_...

MyFunction( *((int*)&v) );
```

OR THIS...

```
#define MAKE_INT_REF(v) *((int*)&(v))

MyFunction( MAKE_INT_REF(v) );
```

The reason is because the compiler can automatically choose the type to use for the enum. It might choose int or it might choose char. You can not be sure across different compilers and platforms. So if you try casting an enum you will end up with unportable code and also very dangerous code, because writing back to such a cast can overwrite other values.

Comment: Be careful: in C++98 an `enum` just has to be backed by something large enough to hold its values. The enum above with only 4 values can be backed by a `char`, if that's what the compiler wants to do.

Comment: True. On second thoughts it is a very bad idea. Deleting that part now.

Comment: I chose to transform the enum type in int as indicated in 1)

Comment: That's what I do as well. But you should take care with the approach. When you have some enum values that only need to be stored as bytes and not needed as byref values then rather use the unsigned char type in the typedef. Not that important if the enum values are stored in variables or parameters, but for classes that have thousands of instances using int generically and then having fields of the typedef type is not a good idea because it will use more memory than needed.

Comment: With enum classes (C++11) you can specify the underlying data type. This way option 2) is viable
`enum class Fruit: int {Apple,Banana,Cherry};`

Comment: If I specify the underlying type of the enum like `enum EnumType : int { ... }`, is using `*(int*)&e` still dangerous?

Answer (score 8):

When you have trouble with an in-line cast it can be helpful to break it out as a separate line:

```
const AgentStatus enumValue = kRUNNING;
...
int intValue = static_cast<int>(enumValue);
DimService("works now", intValue);
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way that doesn't require assigning `intValue` back to `enumValue`?

Comment: Because an enum can use any underlying type of sufficient size, you can't reliably use it for a reference parameter. Let's say your enum has 4 items, and thus the compiler decides to use a `char` internally. How would you then take a `char&` and turn it into an `int&` for the function argument?

Comment: Will it also be a bad practice, if I explicitly define `enum`'s underlying type?

Comment: I don't yet know how this interacts with `enum class`.